# Memfetch with Android Samsung Galaxy Nexus

Tags: android, adb

So I'm trying to use memfetch to dump the memory of a particular process from my Samsung Galaxy Nexus.

I downloaded memfetch from http://lcamtuf.coredump.cx/

Extracted out its contents using the following command:

```
tar -xvf memfetch.tgz
```

Ran an `ls` on my memfetch directory:

```
ls
```

`COPYING Makefile memfetch.c mffind.pl README`

At this stage i'm supposed to run the make command to get my memfetch executable.

Editing the `memfetch.c` file, i removed the `#include page.h` line

So first i downloaded the Android ARM Architecture it with the following command. This was for static cross-compilation for the memfetch:

```
apt-get install gcc-arm0-linux-gnueabi
```

Then i edited `Makefile` at the following areas:

```
FILE = memfetch
CFLAGS = -Wall -09 -static
CC = arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc
```

So success, i had my memfetch executable:

```
make

arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -Wall -09 -static    memfetch.c    -o memfetch

ls

COPYING Makefile memfetch memfetch.c mffind.pl README
```

Then i pushed the memfetch executable into my Android phone:

`adb push memfetch /sdcard/memfetch`

Now from here i worked things from my phone. I ran executed the `adb shell` command and created a directory to store the memfetch exectable, ideally to run it from there:

```
adb shell

su

cd /sdcard

mkdir tmp

mount -t tmpfs tmpfs tmp

cp memfetch tmp

cd tmp

chmod 6755 memfetch
```

Now here's where the problem comes. When i executed the memfetch, i was getting the following error:

```
./memfetch 1197

memfetch 0.05b by Michal Zalewski <lcamtuf@coredump.cx>

Usage ./memfetch [ -sawn ] [ -S xxx ] PID

 -s     - wait for fault signal before generating a dump

 -a     - skip non-anonymous maps (libraries etc)

 -w     - write index file to stdout instead of mfetch.lst

 -m     - avoid mmap(), helps to prevent hanging on some 2.2 boxes

 -S xxx - dump segment containing address xxx (hex) only
```

No matter what PID i tried to dump, i always got the same error. I even tried with various flag combinations but none of them worked :(

Thanks for any help in advanced, let me know if any additional information is required.

Answer (score 0):

That is because of stupidity of Windows Command Line, that make some null characters as input to linux commands.

the solution is, if you don't use other inputs "samwS" comment this lines,

`while ((opt=getopt(argc,(void*)argv, "+samwS:h"))!=EOF)
    switch(opt) {
      case 's': waitsig=1; break;
      case 'a': skipmap=1; break;
      case 'w': textout=1; break;
      case 'm': avoid_mmap=1; break;
      case 'S': if (sscanf(optarg,"%x",&onlyseg)!=1)
                  fatal("Incorrect -S syntax (hex address expected).\n");
                break;
      default:  usage(argv[0]);
    }`

it you use them just comment 
`default:  usage(argv[0]);`

Comment: Also helped in a pure Linux environment.